# SMPS with two sets of output terminals (-v -v v+ v+)

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply

I bought a nominally 30A SMPS like [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TZ2TRRB) to use for powering 5 strings of fifty 5v ws2811 LED pixels:

[image]

The diagram seems to imply that both "-V" terminals are equivalent, and both "+V" terminals are equivalent... but the PSU itself came with no documentation whatsoever.

Can I safely assume that both -V and +V terminals are, in fact, identical, equivalent, and freely-interchangeable if a multimeter indicates 0-ohm resistance (with no power applied to L+N) between the two -V terminals and between the two +V terminals, and +v1 to -v1, +v1 to -v2, +v2 to -v1, and +v2 to -v2 all show "+5v"? Or are there any other potential "gotcha" scenarios lurking that wouldn't necessarily be obvious to someone who's never used PSUs of this type before (as opposed to, "generic black brick with power cord on one end, and DC barrel jack on the other")?

---

(note: I know I need to use a fuse, and I'm planning to inject power between every string of 50 to compensate for voltage drop... I'm just feeling unsure about the reason *why* a value-engineered power supply that probably cut every conceivable corner nevertheless included TWO + and - terminals instead of a single pair, and contemplating the possibility that there might be a subtle *reason* I really need to be aware of & won't necessarily be happy about).

Comment: If the PSU came with no documentation whatsoever, you can't really safely assume *anything*.

Comment: Well, on the other hand, PSUs like this seem to be a pretty generic commodity, so there has to be SOME kind of normal expectation about why they are they way they are, if only so one random factory in China can buy a million of them to use making a million of some other random product.

Comment: @Bitbang3r Given the labeling my first assumption (which I'd check!) would be that they are just two screw terminals to the same node. It could be that a pair of them are sense terminals, in which case you will need to wire the (-) together and the (+) together. But that is unlikely as I'd expect different labeling then. Still, that's also easy to test. Don't assume. Verify. And since you have the unit and I do NOT have the unit, you get to do that job.

Comment: If you received no instructions how to use it, how do you know you can use it safely as there might be things you are unaware of. The fact whether or not the output terminals are just paired together is likely the least of your problems, and fortunately it is also the simplest to find out (they likely are). Remember to connect earth/ground and the PSU likely needs to be in an earthed/grounded metal case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very common for higher-current supplies like that to have multiple positive and negative output terminals.  This allows use of two or more reasonable size wires to be used, rather than requiring a single larger wire that won't fit the common crimp terminals that would normally be used with that type of terminal block.

If you look at the underside of the PC board under the terminal block, you will probably see that the pairs of terminals are connected to a single copper area, confirming that they are not separate supplies.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I safely assume that both -V and +V terminals are, in fact, identical, equivalent, and freely-interchangeable if a multimeter indicates 0-ohm resistance (with no power applied to L+N) between the two -V terminals and between the two +V terminals, and +v1 to -v1, +v1 to -v2, +v2 to -v1, and +v2 to -v2 all show "+5v"?

You just need to test that the two plus terminals are shorted and that the two minus terminals are shorted. In this case they almost certainly will be.

You can buy power supplies with multiple output rails, in which case at least the plus terminals would not be shorted. Most likely you would remember if you'd bought a more expensive power supply with that function, and anyway it would be labeled.

Finally, you probably know this, but power supplies like that with exposed mains terminals should be installed inside some larger enclosure for safety reasons.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty common for power supplies of this type to have two or even three terminals for the output power. You might need to use a bridging connection if you need to safely bring all the current off on a single pair of wires, because the terminal strip rating is possibly not up to the full 30A supply rating. Similar terminal strips from name-brand makers are 15A (Molex) to 30A (Eaton).

Here is a [similar](https://www.meanwellusa.com/upload/pdf/RSP-150/RSP-150-spec.pdf) name-brand (Mean Well) 5V 30A power supply datasheet excerpt showing unambiguously that the connections 4,5 and 6,7 are connected to each other in pairs.

[image]